# The simplest way to expand a tensor so that it has the same dimension as another tensor

Tags: python, numpy

Let `flag` be a one dimensional vector. Let `o1` and `o2` be some arrays of more than one dimension; maybe 2 or 4 or something else.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the following thing in `numpy`?

```
flag = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
# we take o1 and o2 as a four dimensional tensor for an example
o1 = np.ones((10, 2, 4, 4))
o2 = np.zeros((10, 2, 4, 4))
while len(flag.shape) < len(o1.shape):
    flag = np.expand_dims(flag, -1)
o = np.where(flag, o1, o2)
print(o)
```

Comment: The while loop can be replaced with ```flag = flag[(slice(None), *(None,)*(o1.ndim - flag.ndim)]```

Comment: Hi @Kevin. You're right. But could you please explain the utility of `slice(None)` in your code?

Comment: I added an answer to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have looks fine, you could remove the while loop and add the broadcasted dimensions analytically. This can either be done as my comment or you could use `np.reshape`, which is slightly more readable.

```
flag = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
o1 = np.ones((10, 2, 4, 4))
o2 = np.zeros((10, 2, 4, 4))
diff = o1.ndim - flag.ndim
flag = flag.reshape(-1, *(1,)*diff)
o = np.where(flag, o1, o2)
```

You calculate the difference in dimensions between `flag` and `o1`. Then add that many dimensions at the end of `flag` as empty dimensions. A tuple multiplied with a scalar with repeat it `diff` times and it is then being unpacked as an argument to `np.reshape`.

To address my comment, the slice notation `:` is for selecting multiple indices within a range. If you leave it empty it will select all indices and this is equivalent to `slice(None, None, None)` or `slice(None)`. `slice` works much like [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges) in regards to its parameter and i am basically doing the same thing as explained above.